# dbt compile is throwing Object Not Found Error

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am running DBT COMPILE and it is failing with error,

Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
Database Error in model Test_Model
(models/staging/views/Test_Model.sql)
002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
Schema 'TEST_DB.TEST' does not exist or not authorized.

The model is calling a Macro within.

Test_Mode.sql

```
{{ config(
          alias='TEST_MODEL'     
         ,schema='TEST'       
         ,materialized='view'                     
        )
}} 
-- depends_on: {{ ref('BASE_MODEL1') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('BASE_MODEL2') }}
{% if execute %}


{{ generate_view (  ref('BASE_MODEL1') , ref('BASE_MODEL2') , 'ARG1', 'TEST_TABLE' ) }}

{% endif %}
```

The Macro is using dbt_utils.get_single_value(sql_statement) to get some data from a table

```
{% macro generate_view(source,metadata_source,schema_name,table_name) %}

{% if execute %}

    {% set sql_statement %} 
       <SQL Statement>
       from {{ metadata_source }}
    {% endset %}

    {%- set gen_col_list = dbt_utils.get_single_value(sql_statement) -%}

    {% set ns = namespace(gen_col_list_modified=gen_col_list) %}      

    {%- for key, value in extract_columns.items() -%}  
        {%- set ns.gen_col_list_modified = ns.gen_col_list_modified | replace ( 'JSON:' + value['source'], key )  -%}
    {% endfor %}


    SELECT 
        {{ ns.gen_col_list_modified }} 
    FROM {{ source }}
    WHERE _CURRENT_RECORD = TRUE

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

I added if execute at multiple places to avoid this compilation when running dbt compile. But still it is trying to compile the sqls.
If I run DBT RUN it will run everything since these dependent models will be created.
But as part of deployment into upper env dbt compile is executed which will fail the deployment.

Any known issues with if execute statement?

DBT 1.5 version is being used.